# How to listen for changes to a img title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `img` tag. On click, my CMS adds or removes the post from a favorites area. When the post is not in favorites, the `img` looks like:

`<img src="plus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'plus'); return false;" title="Add to favorites">`

When I click on it, the `img` looks like:

`<img src="minus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'minus'); return false;" title="Remove from favorites">`

I want to listen for changes for `title` attribute and write that into some `<div id="some-id"></div>`. If I have an `img` with a `title="Add to favorites"` my code will be like the following after `document.ready` is fired:

```
<div id="some-id">Add to favorites</div>
<img src="plus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'plus'); return false;" title="Add to favorites">
```

When I change the favorite status, the code will be:

```
<div id="some-id">Remove from favorites</div>
<img src="minus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'minus'); return false;" title="Remove from favorites">
```

I'm looking for something like `.change()` but that tracks the `title` attribute.

Comment: Why not to do these changes in `js`?

Comment: @Yuri I want solution in `js` :)

Comment: By `js` I mean not binding directly to tile but also avoiding `onclick` handler in your `html`.

Comment: That comes from my CMS native code, I can't change that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do it! :)

***This code will work if you have just 2 options (2 kinds of title text - Add to favorites and  Remove from favorites)***

At first we take to var current title of image

```
var newTitle = $(".someclass img").attr('title'); // .someclass mean your img parent element class
```

At document ready append title to your `#some-id`.

```
titleChange();
function titleChange() {
    $("#some-id").html(newTitle);
}
```

And then we need to catch `click` on `img` and change our `newTitle` in the opposite value of title.

```
$(".someclass img").click(function() {
  newTitleHolder = $(this).attr('title');
    if(newTitleHolder == 'Add to favorites') {
      newTitle = 'Remove from favorites';
    }else {
      newTitle = 'Add to favorites';
    }
  titleChange();
});
```

Thats all.

And if you have a lot of images on page with same parent class - just put this code into `.each()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="img" src="plus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'plus',$(this)); return false;" title="Add to favorites">
<img src="minus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'minus',$(this)); return false;" title="Remove from favorites">


        function doFavorites(a,b,c)
        {
            if(b=='plus')
            {
                    $('#some-id').text('Remove from favorites');
                    c.attr('title','Remove from favorites');
                    c.attr('src','minus_fav.png');
                    c.attr('onclick','doFavorites('5', 'minus',$(this))');

            }else if(b=='minus')
            {
                    $('#some-id').text('Add to favorites');
                    c.attr('title','Add to favorites');
                    c.attr('src','plus_fav.png');
                    c.attr('onclick','doFavorites('5', 'plus',$(this))');
            }


        }
```

Comment: I cant change img tag. For that I need to change CMS files, I dont want to do that)

Comment: No, I cant add to img tag anything like `onclick="doFavorites('5', 'minus',$(this));` you added `$(this)`

Comment: You have to add $(this)

Comment: I can't! That is native code from my CMS, I cant add or delete

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to attribute, there is no direct way, but you can create a watcher that will check every for value and notify if value has updated.

**Note:** *If you have a lot of images, on which you want to watch, this might have performance impact.*

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nck3aav2/2/)

```js
var originalTitle = "";
var count = 0;
var watchInterval = null;

function updateTitle() {
  originalTitle = $("#img").attr("title");
  console.log("Updating Title")
  $("img").attr("title", "New Title " + count++);
  if (count > 5) {
    console.log("Clearing all intervals")
    window.clearInterval(watchInterval)
  }

  watcher(updateOriginalTitle);
}

function updateOriginalTitle() {
  originalTitle = $("#img").attr("title");
}

function watcher(callback) {
  var watchInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var currTitle = $("#img").attr("title");
    if (currTitle != originalTitle) {
      console.warn("Title has changed");
      if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function")
        callback();
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="test.jpg" id="img" title="test Image" onclick="updateTitle()">;
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems to not working.. for first I cant add or delete any attributes from `<img>` like `onclick`. Is there any simple solution like `.change()` for inputs ?)

Comment: You dont have to change any HTML. Idea is to create a watcher that will check for `title` at certain interval and if value is different, process something. Any change in HTML is only for demonstration purpose. But again, if you have multiple images that you want to watch, this may cause performance issue.

Comment: Yes, I have 200+ images on page.. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't understood very well...

But i think you want to: Everytime that the title changes it writes a "log".

I'd do:

First identify the img.

```
<img id="img" src="plus_fav.png" onclick="doFavorites('5', 'plus'); return false;" title="Add to favorites">
```

And then:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("change","#img",function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#some-id').append(title);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. At first time it works, but next clicks doesn't change #some-id text

Comment: It doesn't changed the text, like nothing or added the same text again?

Comment: Change events don't fire when an attribute value is changed by JS

Comment: Please test your solutions before posting them.